# What is the mistake in my code? Computing prime numbers upto n

Tags: javascript, for-loop, primes

```
function primesuntil(n) {  
    var primes = [2];  
    for (i=3; i < n ; i++) {  
        var j=0;  
        while (j<primes.length) {  
            var quotient = i/primes[j];  
            if (quotient !== math.floor(quotient) {  
                var hasDivisor = false;  
                j++;  
            }  
            else {  
                var hasDivisor = true;  
                j=primes.length+15;  
            }  
        }  
        if (hasDivisor == false)   
            {primes.push(i);}  
        else   
            {var nothing = 3;}  
    }   
    printarray(primes);  
}
```

I want to run this code in JavaScript, which is supposed to print all prime numbers smaller than n, but for some reason it will not run. Have I made a mistake somewhere? When i comment this function out the rest of the code does run.
What the code should do is divide all numbers in the array "primes", and if at some point the quotient equals the 'floor' of that number (meaning it is divisable by the number from the array), hasdivisor becomes true and the number is not added to the array of primes. also, j stops counting (we don't have to divide by the other primes anymore, we know it's not prime). If it doesn't divide any prime numbers smaller than itself, it is prime, so it is added to the list. What's wrong?

Comment: What do you mean, *it will not run*? Was there an error message? Incorrect results? Also, just as a coding note, `else { var nothing = 3; }` is superfluous and can be deleted.

Comment: you can have an if statement without any else? the code should give a result when a button is pressed. there are other input fields that will not give any result when the code is there, but will when the code is commented out.

Comment: Yes! :) An `if` statement can be `if (expression) statement-block` or `if (expression) statement-block else statement-block`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is `if (quotient !== math.floor(quotient))` an extra `)`, and it is `Math.floor`, uppercase `M`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a missing closing parentheses in this line :

```
if (quotient !== math.floor(quotient)) {
```